# true paging by after/before idElement

Tags: sql, paging

I want to be able to get packs elements of base after/before idElement

```
getElementsBatch(.after, id: idElement)
getElementsBatch(.before, id: idElement)
```

but the elements in the sample are not sorted by idElement
How can i do this for SQL

```
SELECT myData FROM myView SORT magicServerSort where ???(after/before idElement)???
```

How can i do this, with minimal load on the base

Comment: No matter what you are trying there is no way for a paging work properly in a database environment without an `order by` clause. That's because the database won't garante a order for the rows you are fetching no matters what filters (where clause) you are using

Comment: Is normal paging is something "out of the ordinary?" Surely there ready practice / Paterna realizing that everything will be easy enough, and almost out of the box.

Comment: Yes, of course there are. But since you didn't provide any more information about your setup (as language you are working, RDBMs you are using) we can't do much to help you. What I said is still valid with your little piece of code and for SQL. You have to order by something to be able to create a paging. In pure SQL most RDBMs deals with LIMIT clause or ROW_NUMBER function either way you still need to use an order by clause. Something like (for mysql): `select m.* from myView m where [some_conditions] ORDER BY someField LIMIT 10 OFFSET 450` knowing that someField must be something indexed...

Comment: ... Limit clause will bring you 10 rows offset clause states from what position in the result set that 10 rows will be fetched